# Shared probability function of a discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The same experiment with probability $p$ of success is repeated until it has succeeded 3 times.

- Let $X$ be the number of experiments until the first success
- Let $Y$ be the number of experiments in total

I need to:

1. Find the shared probability function of $X$ and $Y$, specify the possible range of values for the function
2. Find the probability function of X if it known that $Y=j, \space j\ge3$, specify the possible range of values for the function
3. Calculate $P\{Y-X=9\}$

So for (1) I did
$$P\{X=i, Y=j\}=(1-p)^{i-1}p\cdot \binom{j-i-1}{1}p^2(1-p)^{j-i-2}=\binom{j-i-1}{1}p^3(1-p)^{j-3}\space\space\space i\ge1, j\ge i+3$$

For (2)
$$P\{Y=j\}=\binom{j-1}{2}p^3(1-p)^{j-3}$$
$$P\{X=i|Y=j\}=\frac{\binom{j-i-1}{1}p^3(1-p)^{j-3}}{\binom{j-1}{2}p^3(1-p)^{j-3}}=\frac{\binom{j-i-1}{1}}{\binom{j-1}{2}}=\frac{2(j-i-1)}{(j-1)(j-2)}=\frac{2j-2i-2}{j^2-3j+2}, \space\space\space i\ge 1$$

And for (3)
$$P\{Y-X=9\}=P\{Y=X+9\}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P\{X=i, Y=i+9\}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \binom{i+9-i-1}{1}p^3(1-p)^{i+9-3}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\binom{8}{1}p^3(1-p)^{i+6}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}8p^3(1-p)^{i+6}=8p^3(1-p)^7\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^i=8p^3(1-p)^7\frac{1}{p}=8p^2(1-p)^7$$

but when I test my results for (2) I get weird results:
$$P\{X=3|Y=3\} = -1$$
when tt should be $0$

and
$$P\{X=2|Y=4\}=1/3$$
when I expected it to be $\frac{1}{2}$ as $X$ can only be $1$ or $2$

my results for (1) and (3) seems to be correct so I don't understand what's wrong with my answer for (2)

Comment: In the line $P\{X=i|Y=j\}=\frac{\binom{j-i-1}{1}p^3(1-p)^{j-3}}{\binom{j-1}{2}p^3(1-p)^{j-3}}$, when $i=j=3$ you get a $\binom{-1}{1}$ in the numerator. I think the equation is correct for $j\geq i+2$, and for $j<i+2$ the probability is 0.